# How to convert a GCP kubeflow dataset into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run my first kubeflow pipeline in `GCP`.  This basically ingest data from a BigQuery data frame then sends that to a dataset where the next component in the pipeline pulls the dataset and runs that data inside a PyMC model.  But I'm getting errors, because the code does not recognize the dataset as a dataframe.

I've tried: `df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)` but that errors out.

Has anyone had success converting a GCP kubeflow dataset into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out....I needed to put a `.output` on the `input_data` variable inside the `DataFrame` function.